# How do I stop remote access?

Tags: applications, samsung

I have a Samsung Galaxy 10. Somehow, my ex has gained access and is able to see my texts and video calls in Whatsapp and Telegram, etc. He is listening to or watching every conversation. I became suspicious when he mentioned details from private conversations. He admitted to mirroring my device but will not provide details and says he has stopped. However, I believe it is still happening. When I am on video calls in WhatsApp and Telegram, the calls freeze and it seems the signal is bad even when I am on WiFi or have full bars. How can I stop this? Please help.

Comment: remove all [google](https://www.bettertechtips.com/android/remove-google-account-from-android-smartphone)/samsung accounts from settings. even if you are using another phone it still might possible to mirror WhatsApp web. therefore i recommend to unregister all services and change all passwords. use another phone number for Whatsapp Telegram etc. besides this, inform all your friends and contacts about your phone probably has been compromised and they might receive fake messages from attacker in your name

Comment: You may also contact the support form WhatsApp and Telegram, to check if they can see anything suspicious happening with your accounts.And also the police, since eavesdropping is a serious offense! In most countries, recording a a conversation is illegal even if is it your own (if other parties do not consent)!

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how far your ex went with installing unwanted software on your device.

In most cases a factory restore would remove unwanted software.

Just make sure to copy your important data (photos/messages/etc.) somewhere else before doing it.

Answer (score 1):

If someone has gained remote access to your Android device, it is compromised.  The only way to *likely* remove the malware is to perform a factory reset.

1. Backup your data.
2. Perform a factory reset.

I would not backup all your apps, just the data itself, as you really can't trust anything on the device.

If you don't need any of the data on the device, just factory reset it.  That's the second safest thing you can do without buying a new device.  (Outside of buying a new device, the safest thing is wiping all the non-volatile storage, but that's a more in-depth procedure.)

Note that even a factory reset does not truly reset the entire device (reportedly true on iPhones *and* Android devices).  See: [With Android, does a factory reset truly reset the device to the same as it was when it left the factory (unlike an iPhone)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/234098/with-android-does-a-factory-reset-truly-reset-the-device-to-the-same-as-it-was)

Comment: @alecxs Your recommendation to not use the same Google/Samsung account is a good one.  Why do you recommend removing all accounts before a factory reset since the factory reset will remove them from the device?

Comment: behavior depends on how factory reset is performed. on some devices factory reset from recovery won't remove google account. instead factory reset protection (FRP lock) is activated (requires unlocking with bonded google account which survived factory reset). on Xiaomi devices we have additional fun with Mi account (even on already unlocked bootloader) therefore assume for samsung account it's similar protection (but don't know for sure)

Comment: @alecxs Thanks for the info.  They really should rename *"factory reset"* to ***"kinda sorta reset"***.

Comment: @rockpaperlz-mask-it-or-casket A true factory reset would require manually re-flashing an older version of your device firmware. This may not be safe if the bootloader has been updated by a system update, or even impossible without voiding warranty... There is a reason to the madness though... If you reset to a vulnerable version of your OS, your device could (in some circumstances) get targeted and quickly be compromized as soon as you connect it to anything (wifi, mobile data, etc).

Comment: @svin83 Thanks.  It's one of the (many) things I find concerning about Microsoft's Windows.  Millions of users connect it to the internet while it is in an extremely vulnerable state in order to download updates to reduce *some* of the vulnerabilities.  The obvious solution for all operating systems (Android, Windows, Linux, macOS, et. al.) is to obtain the updates from a more secure device or directly from an external storage medium (e.g. DVD-ROM or CD-ROM).

Comment: @svin83 Regarding the bootloader, wouldn't a true factory reset perform a reset of that as well, removing that possible risk?  And regarding warranties, those are arbitrarily written by the manufacturer, so they could certainly allow a true factory reset.  It might actually save them in support and warranty costs, because a true factory reset would make the device to be identical to how it was when it was new out of the box.

Comment: Production systems should fetch the first, and most critical updates from a trusted local repository. Withdrawing administrative privileges from all users on Windows will block MANY attack vectors.

Comment: @rockpaperlz-mask-it-or-casket Boot loaders are often protected from flashing except by vendor approved updates. It may be possible if devices come with extra immutable storage containing the original OS, but who wants to pay for that?

Comment: @svin83 I agree *completely* that security updates should be fetched from a trusted local repo, but unfortunately Windows 10 isn't designed that way at all for the hundreds of millions (are they up to billions yet?) of home and small business users on Win10.  I think it's a safe estimate that well under 1% of home and small business Windows 10 users get their updates that way.

Comment: @svin83 Good point about having an immutable *copy* of the OS.  I wonder if it's more of a physical space issue rather than cost.  I haven't priced ROM chips in years... any idea of the size & cost (when purchased in bulk) of ROM chips these days (sufficient in size to store Android)?