# With Android, does a factory reset truly reset the device to the same as it was when it left the factory (unlike an iPhone)?

Tags: security, factory-reset, storage, privacy, delete

When you reset an iPhone, my understanding is that [the device does not truly get reset to how it was when it exited the factory](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/411605/is-it-possible-to-completely-reset-an-iphone-so-its-software-firmware-is-guarant).

What about with an Android device?  Does performing a *factory reset* on an Android device **always** reset the device to how it actually left the factory?

I decided to ask this question to help our community generate accurate answers to [this other one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/234095/how-do-i-stop-remote-access).

Comment: Only the user data partition is reset. The system partition stays and therefore all updates. But this is the same for iPhone. If an app manages to get root permissions e.g. using a vulnerability of the installed system software it can manipulate the system partition and make changes that are persistent to factory reset.

Comment: android has factory reset protection (FRP) therefore some partitions will survive

Comment: @alecxs Thanks. Which partitions?

Comment: idk. that differs. frp at least, maybe misc param persist? on mediatek maybe nvram seccfg para proinfo flashinfo?

Comment: Basically every partition that is not user accessible is untouched and persists... There are 20+ partitions on same Android devices, /data is the primary mount point cleared with a factory reset.

Comment: @acejavelin Answers beget more questions! :)  Many apps store databases that are not user-accessible (without root).  Is the partition where those are stored deleted?

Comment: That is user data, those are all cleared out. They are not directly user accessible, but are user specific data... All files in that base partition of /data are cleared.

Comment: @acejavelin Got it. Thank you.  It's 30 seconds too late to be able to edit your comment above, but I think if we replace "user accessible" with "user data" it would be accurate, correct?

Comment: @acejavelin of course, i am talking about partitions which contain userdata (like frp) or partitions with temp data (like fota/misc) or partitions with device specific data (calibration data, bad blocks info etc) which can survive, i think we can safely exclude partitions which are included in stock ROM. afaik only cache userdata metadata is wiped for sure on factory reset

Comment: If the OS is hacked (like a custom firmware or similar), then anything goes. It can present you a fake "factory reset" menu point, then pretend it is cleaning (by showing you some images on the screen that look like a real factory reset process) but really not erase anything. Reflashing a new firmware (colloquially known as "custom ROM", or an original one) might solve this for most cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the same as an iPhone I believe. A "factory reset" removes all information in the data and user partition, but leaves everything in the system and associated partitions as is. That means if you got an upgrade or update that changed anything in the system partition, it would remain after a "factory reset".

The reality is that a "factory reset" is kind of a misnomer in this case, it's more of a "user reset" than anything else if we were being more accurate.

Comment: So that means that if someone installed a malicious ROM on an Android, it would persist after a "factory reset"?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Yes, but for this to occur they would need to unlock the bootloader, so there would be evidence of tampering. Most modern phones cannot have their bootloader unlocked though, and without that and root access to the device, the system partition contents cannot be modified.

Comment: Thanks.  I haven't installed a custom ROM in a few years.  If unlocking the bootloader is required to do this, and most modern Android devices cannot have their bootloaders unlocked, does that mean that custom ROMs are not available on most modern Android devices?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Sadly, that is correct. Very few new(ish) devices outside of Google Pixel, OnePlus, some Samsungs and Moto devices, and a few others, allow the bootloader to be unlocked and rooting to occur, and if it does then tampering is evident as once the bootloader is unlocked, it cannot be relocked without flashing a signed factory image (meaning it is stock), so the evidence of tampering is very easy to determine.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. Does the bootloader need to unlocked for the device to rooted?  Also, is there a good list anywhere of which devices allow unlocking the bootloader?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Yes... Rooting cannot occur unless the bootloader is unlocked, and I don't know of a list. There are always exceptions, but each year that list gets smaller and smaller. Basically, if you are looking for a phone to root or use custom ROMs on, do your research ahead of time, because the list of phones that can do it is miniscule compared to the ones that cannot. A safe bet is always Google Pixel or OnePlus retail phones, but even some carrier branded Pixels cannot be unlocked.

Comment: Thank you for the additional info!  I had no idea that the carrier branded Pixels could not be unlocked.  Good to know.  Those Pixels are tempting, but a 12MP camera is just not making the cut in 2021, as I like to print enlargements.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Honestly, I own and use a Pixel 4a... Once you get above 8 or so MP, the pixels don't matter, but how the software handles them is the primary issue. My 12MP Pixel will easily take better shots in most conditions than most cameras with double it's native resolution... There is a reason Pixel cameras are still among the best rated cell phone cameras of all time. But we are getting off track and getting "chatty" warnings from Stack Exchange, as this is not a discussion forum. But honestly I still feel Pixel devices are the best value out there.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket If you feel my answer to question is correct and complete, please accept it. If you think it needs more clarification to the original question, let me know and I will adjust it.

Comment: Sure.  I upvoted your answer right away, but was waiting to see if any other answers trickled in before accepting it.  Can you expand your answer a little on what you mean by data and user partition?  When I look at the root folder of an Android device I see `data`, but not `user`.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket In most devices the user folder is inside /data and is /data/user or /data/usr or /mnt/user, and some devices have them somewhere else, which is why I did not not reference "/data" specifically, but said the data and user partition as their exact location can vary from device to device and even between Android versions.

Comment: Thanks.  Do the programmers of the ROM decide which folder to use?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Partially, it also depends on the Android version and the current file structure recommendations by Google.

Comment: Thanks.  I have accepted your answer.  Thanks for your help and for sharing your knowledge.