# Can factory reset recover deleted built-in apps?

Tags: rooting, system-apps

If ill root my phone and delete the browser and the play store for example... and then ill go into recovery mode and make a factory reset, will those app will come back?

If yes, is there a way to prevent simple factory rest to recover those app?
ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have deleted those apps from system partition using root permissions (via `su`) then a factory reset will not restore those apps (see also [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/234098/with-android-does-a-factory-reset-truly-reset-the-device-to-the-same-as-it-was) for details).

Only installing a new firmware or manually installing an "firmware update" via recovery that contains the deleted apps (e.g. a OpenGApps package containing PlayStore) can restore them.

Comment: Is this app will do the job, or do i need to delete specific files manually? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jumobile.manager.systemapp

Comment: @Joe For deleting a system app you need to remount the system partition writable. How to do so can differ from device to device, therefore such apps can work or not. You only know if it works if you have tried it. Note that deleting the wrong app can make your system unbootable, hence you would have to reflash the system firmware (if it is available).

Comment: I'm speaking about a rooted phone, i know how to do that, its very easy on Pixel and OnePluse phone's. in my old phone that i already rooted i use this app and give her SU permissions. and it deleted the system app's i wanted. My question is, if this app delete those app properly to prevent recovery by factory reset or not?

Comment: @Joe Sorry but I cant' answer you the question if an app works "properly" or not. Try it out and check what it modifies. Usually a system app is just an `.apk` file and an `.odex` file of the same name in the same directory.

Comment: The last sentence you said was the answer I was looking for! ty man!

Comment: I have anther question.. maybe you'll know... I want to disable the recovery mode, It happened to me once without intention... I hade a Homtom phone, and i rooted him, and then i tried to put TWRP recovery. I didn't succeed, but what happened was a black screen every time i tried to enter recovery mode. that's what im looking for, something like that.. replace the stock recovery with a broken recovery mode or whatever will do the same work.

Comment: @Joe You can do so and "lock" the recovery but someone who has access to your device can simple flash a different recovery and thus make it work again.

Comment: I know that with an access to my device you can flash a different recovery, but most people where i live don't know how to do that, and even they don't know to root or even to unlock the bootloader. most people won't know to recognize the problem, they are not so smart. Of course there are those who know and can do it, but it does add a lot of security to my phone, and besides that there are other reasons I want to do it besides security. What I do not know is how to do it in the simplest way. what happened to me then was by mistake or by luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120132/discussion-between-joe-and-robert).